# Redundant nullcheck of value known to be null

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a piece of code which looks something like this:

```
private void methodA(String a String b){
  Employee e1=null;
  foobar(e1,b); //line 1
  //do something
  if(e1!=null){ //line 2
    //flow1
  }else{
    //flow2
  }
}
private void foobar(Employee e, String a){
  e= new Employee();
  //do stuff
}
```

When I run findBugs for this class, it shows me two warnings at line1 -

```
Load of known null value
The variable referenced at this point is known to be null due to an earlier check against null. Although this is valid, it might be a mistake (perhaps you intended to refer to a different variable, or perhaps the earlier check to see if the variable is null should have been a check to see if it was nonnull).
```

and at line 2 :

```
Redundant nullcheck of value known to be null
This method contains a redundant check of a known null value against the constant null.
```

To avoid these warnings I instead did the following:

```
private void methodA(String a String b){
  Employee e1 = foobar(b); //line 1
  //do something
  if(e1!=null){ //line 2
    //flow1
  }else{
    //flow2
  }
}
private Employee foobar(String a){
 if("some_value".equals(a)){
  Employee e= new Employee();
  //do stuff
  return e;
  }
return null;
}
```

Doing this removes the warnings from findbugs, but my question is this change absolutely  necessary, or rather what could be the impacts going with the first approach?

Comment: In the first approach `e1` will never not be null, because parameters are passed by value (i.e. the value of `e1` well be copied to `e` and nothing you do to `e` inside that method will affect `e1`).

Comment: oh, yeah you are right, I missed an obvious one there . Thanks. :)

Comment: It seems that `method` and `foobar` should have the same name.  Could you fix your code?  Making it compile (adding import statements and used classes) would be even more useful.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, thanks for pointing it out,I changed it in the question. Also, I added this code just as a sample, for the question,and kept it short for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Employee e1=null;
foobar(e1,b);
```

This is not correct, because of `foobar()` gets `null` and e1 cannot be referenced to the object after it. So `if(e1!=null)` is always **false**.

---

```
Employee e1=null;
...
private void foobar(Employee e, String a){
  e= new Employee();
  //do stuff
}
```

`e` refers to the new object, but this is a **local variable** for the method.